# How can I avoid this Access SQL kludge?

Tags: sql, ms-access

The goal is to return the info from the latest assignment for each 'eligibility'. If there are two assignments with the same date, still only return one row per 'eligibility' with the assignment picked being arbitrary.

Current method:

qCurrentAssignment_sub:

```
SELECT tblAssignment.EligibilityID, Max(DateAdd("s",[AssignmentID] Mod 10000,[AssignmentDate])) AS DatePlusIDMod10000
FROM tblAssignment
GROUP BY tblAssignment.EligibilityID;
```

qCurrentAssignment:

```
SELECT tblAssignment.AssignedTo, tblAssignment.AssignedBy, tblAssignment.Method, tblAssignment.AssignmentDate
FROM qCurrentAssignment_sub INNER JOIN tblAssignment ON 
    (qCurrentAssignment_sub.EligibilityID = tblAssignment.EligibilityID) AND 
    (qCurrentAssignment_sub.DatePlusIDMod10000 = DateAdd("s",[AssignmentID] Mod 10000,[AssignmentDate]));
```

Comment: What is the question / problem?

Comment: The method used to avoid getting more than one row given a duplicate date is to add a number of seconds equal to the row's ID to the dates to make them non-identical.

Which is stupid.

Comment: If your data doesn't have unique identifying data, it's not really a kludge to have to provide something unique. But I would wonder if your data is properly structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated From Comment**

If given

- multiple assignmentid for each assignmentid
- you want the assignmentid associated with the max assignmentDate
- If more than one assignmentid exist for the max(assignmentDate) then you want the max assignmentid

Change qCurrentAssignment_sub to

qCurrentAssignment_sub

```sql
  SELECT
        eligibilityid,
        MAX(assignmentid) assignmentid

    FROM
        tblassignment 
        INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT tblassignment.eligibilityid, 
               MAX(AssignmentDate) AssignmentDate 
        FROM   tblassignment 
        GROUP  BY tblassignment.eligibilityid) maxAssignmentDate
        ON tblassignment.eligibilityid = maxAssignmentDate.eligibilityid
           and maxAssignmentDate.AssignmentDate = maxAssignmentDate.AssignmentDate
    GROUP BY 
        eligibilityid
```

Then join back to tblassignment on assignmentid. This makes the join a little cleaner as well

qCurrentAssignment

```sql
SELECT tblassignment.assignedto, 
       tblassignment.assignedby, 
       tblassignment.method, 
       tblassignment.assignmentdate 
FROM   tblassignment 
       INNER JOIN qcurrentassignment_sub 
         ON tblassignment.assignmentid = qcurrentassignment_sub.assignmentid
```

Comment: This has the opposite issue, two assignments with different dates but the same EligibilityID will result in two rows returned, though only one row will be returned if the two assignments have the same date.

Comment: @τεκ To clarify you want one and only one assignmentid for each EligibilityID. You want the one with the max Assignement Date but if two exist on a given assignment date then still get one and only one assignmentid.